# Floorplan with GPS location markers

Tags: codenameone

I want to be able to display a floor plan with pan / zoom capability and overlay location markers using GPS coordinates (similar to the uber clone but with a location plan as the base rather than a map).

What would be the best avenue to explore?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location manager to get a location listener. You can use the lat/lng values from the location listener to position the image correctly using either an image viewer or manually using `drawImage` (from `Graphics`). You would need to know the latitude and longitude values corresponding to the image corners so you can position the image correctly.